# Is it possible to run LSI SAS 9211-8i PCI-E 8 in PCI-E 16 Slot?

Tags: raid, sas, lsi

I just bought an LSI SAS 9211-8i HBA(Host bus adapter) to use with my new hardware.
I realized after looking at the card that it required an x8 slot and my new mobo only x16 available. I keep on reading that PCI-E specs are backwards compatable however when I try to install Windows 7 on it it does not find the RAID Controller and now I am really confused.
Can anyone help with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in the general case you can install PCI-E cards in any PCI-E slot that will physically accept the card. If there are fewer PCI-E lanes available than the card requires, it should run a little slower but still run. If there are more lanes, it will just use what it needs.

PCI-E 1 and PCI-E 2 should not be a problem either.

Regarding Windows 7 not finding the RAID controller, I do of course assume that you're using the proper driver for the RAID card? And that if you're installing the OS onto a RAID volume, that you're loading the drivers during installation...

If all this is the case, then my guess is that you're using a consumer class desktop motherboard. Some desktop boards have PCI-E x16 slot which will only work with graphics cards. This goes against the intentions of PCI-E, but some manufacturers don't bother to do anything about this, since desktop machines almost always use the fastest PCI-E slots for graphics. Try contacting your motherboard maker / PC suppliers support..

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
By the way this is the motherboard that I am using:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131365
It is an ASUS P6T Deluxe V2 LGA 1366 Intel X58 ATX. No where does it state that the PCIe x16 slots only work with Graphics cards and I checked a couple of times and the RAID Controller that I got actually states that Windows 7 supports it out of the box with no drivers needed. I have even attempted at installing a RAID Driver for it but the installer does not recognize it.
I RMAed my mobo and I hope I don't have to get the RAID RMAed also.

Comment: Try writing to Asus's tech support, and ask if the mobo supports a non-graphics card in its x16 slot. Of course I don't know that specific motherboard, but it sounds like a likely cause of the problem. Could also be that the RAID controller is dead of course, which you can check if you have another machine to test it in.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can plug x8 cards into x16 slots.  It's more likely that your problem is that you've got a PCIe Gen2 (version 2.0) card in a motherboard which doesn't know how to deal with that.  Try a BIOS upgrade.