# LSI 9211-4i; with CentOS but no drives showing up to linux

Tags: linux, centos, lsi

So I am trying to move an appliance from freeNAS to CentOS, but after installing the OS it just can't find the drives! Much like: [Just installed LSI 9211; no drives showing up to Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/699218/just-installed-lsi-9211-no-drives-showing-up-to-linux) (even their ZFS plan but without so easy a solution.)

```
# lspci | grep LSI
02:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Broadcom / LSI SAS2004 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Spitfire] (rev 03)
```

Like my linked friend `lsblk` and `udevadm info --export-db` show nothing. Although the LSI Logic Configuration Utility does show the 24 drives!

I doubt this is to do with failing hardware since it was working okay on FreeNAS (but maybe) and I moved the card over a PCI slot.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I may need to look lack of RHEL support =/ https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=71862

Answer (score 0):

There are repositories with kmod-xxx packages that can contain modules you might need, like: https://elrepo.org/linux/elrepo/el8/x86_64/RPMS/